# Write Data from Google Spreadsheets to a BigQuery Table

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to write data from Google Spreadsheets to a BigQuery Table.
Are there any sources which I can tap into to learn how to do this?

(Something like this would be awesome:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/bigquery_tutorial)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far?

Before writing actual code, I see two ways:

- Send data through a POST request, using https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app and https://developers.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery#loaddatapostrequest.
- Otherwise you could upload the data to Google Cloud Storage, and insert a job that loads it into BigQuery. Take a look at http://blog.knoldus.com/2013/01/19/google-apps-script-to-store-data-on-google-cloud-sorage/.