# How to insert data from Google spreadsheets and ScriptDBs into BigQuery tables using Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

We have successfully deployed Google Apps Script based web applications to teams of users, those applications allow the users to log their daily activities via a simple GUI. The log data is collected per team using Google spreadsheets or ScriptDBs, depending on the size of the team.

We now want to go one step further and do analysis and reports on the user activity data across the teams. Given the amount of data, BigQuery looks like a good technology to do that. We are thinking about using Google Apps Scripts to push the data automatically on a regular (e.g. daily basis) to the BigQuery table(s). We are wondering what the best practices are to do that with the data originating from Google spreadsheets and ScriptDBs.

Unlike in previous cases, just from simply reading through the BigQuery API documentation and code snippets it does not become obvious to us what the recommended approach is.

The hint we found so far:
[Write Data from Google Spreadsheets to a BigQuery Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196259/write-data-from-google-spreadsheets-to-a-bigquery-table)

Comment: Look at the code in the s.o. answer you linked to. It has all you need to push data rows from apps script to bigquery.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any examples for it, but you can use Apps Script's built-in [BigQuery service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_bigquery) to upload data directly.

```
BigQuery.Jobs.insert(resource, mediaData, optionalArgs)
```

The mediaData parameter was recently added, and allows you to pass in the CSV data as a blob which gets sent directly to BigQuery.